# Launching Visual Studio from WebMatrix 2 opens wrong version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, registry, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

I'm using Microsoft **WebMatrix 2** to work on a simple ASP.NET WebPages site. When you are in the **Files** view, there is a **Visual Studio Launch** button that should open up the site Solution in **Visual Studio 2012**. On my machine I also have Visual Studio 2010 installed and that is the version that gets opened when I click on the button.

[image]

How can I make sure that Visual Studio 2012 is opened?

I'm working on Windows 8 but I am pretty sure this applies to Windows 7 and XP as well. I suspect I may have installed 2012 before 2010 which may explain how my machine got into this state but I can't remember for sure.

Answer (score 18):

Thanks to [Mike Brind](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/) for the technical details of the solution in his blog post [WebMatrix Opens Wrong Version Of Visual Studio](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/175/WebMatrix-Opens-Wrong-Version-Of-Visual-Studio).

Basically you need to update these registry entries to point to the correct version of Studio. Remember to be careful when modifying the [Windows Registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/136393)!

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.DTE\CLSID
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.DTE\CurVer
```

Running the commands below will backup the registry entries first and set the values to be Visual Studio 2012. You will need to open an administrator / elevated priviledge command prompt to execute them.

```
reg export HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.DTE %HOMEPATH%\Documents\VisualStudio.DTE-RegistryKeyBackup.reg
reg add HKCR\VisualStudio.DTE\CLSID /ve /d {059618E6-4639-4D1A-A248-1384E368D5C3} /f
reg add HKCR\VisualStudio.DTE\CurVer /ve /d VisualStudio.DTE.11.0 /f
```

Comment: For reference, VS2013 is CLSID `{3C0D7ACB-790B-4437-8DD2-815CA17C474D}` and CurVer `VisualStudio.DTE.12.0`

Comment: For reference, CurVer for VS 2015 is VisualStudio.DTE.14.0 and the CLSID is A2FA2136-EB44-4D10-A1D3-6FE1D63A7C05 (from Mike's linked blog post)