# Website For Web Service (Beginner Help)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web

If I have an API of a WebService and i were asked to make a website for this WebService how can I do it using c#(Visual Studio) ?

Open a project like : visual c# -> ASP.NET Web Application? like programming a standard website ? or do I need to open a different type of project or configure other things ?

If any one got a nice tutorial or something similar i appreciate it...a lot!

> *A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step.*

Comment: "A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single Google search"

Comment: When asking a question it's better to show what you have done. You are asking for something you can read in a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great tutorial that will teach you how to build an MVC website that uses a WebAPI:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Did you heard about Webmatrix? http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/. Its a great tool to create websites within minutes. And they have also a lot of tutorials for beginners: http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=webmatrix-introduction.

Comment: Thank you Luis but i have a question before i try this tool, does the output of this tool is ASPX and HTML files so I could transfer my project from Webmatrix to Visual Studio or i'm bound to Webmatrix? 
Example: say I develop a site in Webmatrix I could continue develop it in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Take a look at this Question for some insight on your comment:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983217/launching-visual-studio-from-webmatrix-2-opens-wrong-version

Comment: Yes. You can easily switch between Webmatrix and Visual Studio. They are 100% compatible.